# Algebraic closure of rational fractions

Tags: field-theory

I work with matrices whose entries are rational fractions of polynomials
$$ M(x) = \left( \begin{array}{ccc} R_{11}(x) & \dots & R_{1n}(x) \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ R_{n1}(x) & \dots & R_{nn}(x) \end{array} \right), _ \ R_{ij} \in \mathbb R(x)  $$
and I am interested in the eigenvalues of $M$. I guess (although I don't have the proof of that statement) that every element of the algebraic closure of $\mathbb R(x)$ is a potential eigenvalue of such matrix.

So my question is the following, what can we say about the algebraic closure of the field of rational fractions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: DO you mean ${\mathbb Q}[x]$ rather than ${\mathbb R}[x]$?

Comment: Maybe I mixed up the notations, I mean the field of fractions of polynomials with real coefficients.

Comment: Oh, okay. That is normally denoted by round brackets, as in ${\mathbb R}(x)$. I thought you meant the coefficients of the poynomials were rational.